# Converting JSON data into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following JSON incoming data (note it have comma in it).

```
var data = '["QUAIL, TX","QUAKER CITY, OH","QUAKER, CT","QUAKER STREET, NY"]';
```

Now I want to convert it into JavaScript array but not sure what is the best approach to do this? I have tried JSON.parse(data) which throws exception and I have tried to split data by '",' but it gets the wrong value at first and in end. Any idea what is the best strategy here?

```
     data = JSON.stringify(data);
     data = data.split('",');
```

PS: I have looked at most of the questions but none of them was relevant here.

Comment: Try this to convert your data to javascript array: `var data = data`. Now `data` is going to be an array.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: What is your issue actually about?

Comment: Your original `data` variable is already an array, please provide the JSON string that you are working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas in JSON string won't cause `JSON.parse()` to throw exception. See this code:

```
var a = '["QUAIL, TX","QUAKER CITY, OH","QUAKER, CT","QUAKER STREET, NY"]';
var b = JSON.parse( a );
alert( b[0] );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sTuSV/

It is about something different being wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work - but I am assuming what you have given 'is' your data structure. If your JSON is different, then what I have below will not work.

```
var data = ["QUAIL, TX","QUAKER CITY, OH","QUAKER, CT","QUAKER STREET, NY"].toString().split(',');

 //returns ["QUAIL", " TX", "QUAKER CITY", " OH", "QUAKER", " CT", "QUAKER STREET", " NY"]
```

if you want to get rid of the white space:

```
var data = ["QUAIL, TX","QUAKER CITY, OH","QUAKER, CT","QUAKER STREET, NY"].toString().replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
     // returns ["QUAIL", "TX", "QUAKERCITY", "OH", "QUAKER", "CT", "QUAKERSTREET", "NY"]
```